# How to prevent PropertyGrid.Update() from slowing down

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Xceed `PropertyGrid` control for WPF.

Since I need to refresh object values in grid frequently and fast, I was using property grid's `Update` method: https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid~Update.html

However, I have noticed that this becomes slower and slower each time the method is called. For example, this code simulates gradual slow down:

```
// Takes 618 ms
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) PGMain.Update();

// Takes 1649 ms
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) PGMain.Update();

// Takes 2739 ms
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) PGMain.Update();

// Takes 3730 ms
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) PGMain.Update();
```

Someone else encountered this bug/problem?

Is there a workaround/fix other than re-assigning `SelectedObject` (which is slow)?

Comment: I would post it to the XCeed forums.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this question has been asked but anyway.
I am having the same issue right now and I read your post on the xceed forum as well. I could find any good solution so I started to try some things...

Don't ask me why but in my case it turned out to remain in stable update times if I did the following things:

1. `<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="PropertyGrid_Eigenschaften" Margin="3" NameColumnWidth="215" SelectedObject="{Binding}"/>`
2. `PropertyGrid_Eigenschaften.DataContext = Achse.Eigenschaften;`
3. all properties in my class have a `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]` attribute
4. Refresh the PropertyGrid periodically with `PropertyGrid_Eigenschaften.Update();`

It is not as fast as I would like it to be, but at least it is a first step in the right direction.